# Compile using Makefile on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to compile my code using MakeFile in a Windows environment. I have created a Makefile in Linux but don't have any idea how to create and run in Windows. I have installed MinGW and also edited the environment variable path. I have tried running the Makefile like I was doing in a Linux environment, but I'm not able to run it. Can anyone please share any link.

This is my simple Makefile

```
CC = g++

all: Exe 

Exe : main.o Hello.o

    $(CC) -o Exe main.o Hello.o

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp

Hello.o: Hello.cpp
    $(CC) -c Hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o main.o Hello.o
```

I am running it from the command prompt **make MakeFile** and every time it prompts with the message, **makefile up to date**. It is not doing anything, not even generating an executable.

Comment: `but I'm not able to run` - because the command is not found, or because of an error with the Makefile syntax?

Comment: You probably intended `make --file Makefile` even though that's the default input file. Without the `--file`, you're naming the target, not the input make file.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is almost the same. It's really depend if you added specific command (like using `find`, `grep`, ...).

You should add the error reported by `make` command to your question.
Without more information we cannot guess where is the problem

**Edit:** I did not understand that you do not find the make command. The `make` command is sometime named `mingw32-make.exe`. It's really depend which version and type of MinGW you installed

**Edit2:** The command line to type is `make` (or `mingw32-make.exe`) and not `make Makefile`
Take a look at the man of `make`

In the `clean:` section, do not use `rm`, this command does not exist on Windows

Comment: "make: MakeFile is up to date" this message it is giving every time i am running.

Comment: You only to run `make` and not `make Makefile`

Answer (score 2):

Goto bin directory in MinGW and check whether you have a file named make.exe if you don't have it then rename mingw32-make.exe to make.exe

As I remember normally make.exe is named mingw32-make.exe in the MinGW distribution, I don't know why they do so, but renaming it to make.exe can solve the problem in most of the cases.

Comment: i have Changed the name but still not able to run it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.... got the bug i was running using   make MakeFile instead of make

Comment: are you sure that the make program you are running is the `make` in mainGw bin directory, use `where make` to find the location of the make file you are using