# Compile using makefile in Windows with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, mingw

I have a problem with the following makefile in Windows. Although it worked in Linux, I get an error now using MinGW in Windows.
I checked the article on this page: [Compile using MakeFile in Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158931/compile-using-makefile-in-window), but I still have no success.

```
CC      = c++
CFLAGS  = -Wall -g

ODIR    = /OBJ
CFILES  := $(wildcard SRC/*.cpp)
OFILES  := $(addprefix OBJ/,$(notdir $(CFILES:.cpp=.o)))

meshl:  $(OFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OFILES)
OBJ/%.o: SRC/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f OBJ/*.o
```

When I try to compile it in the command prompt, the following message appears:

```
OBJ/mpoint.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:9: recipe for target 'meshl' failed
make: ***[meshl] Error 1
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Does it still happen after `make clean`?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot even execute make clean properly. I get the following error message in the command prompt:

Comment: process_begin: CreateProcess<NULL, rm -f OBJ/*.o, ...> failed.

Comment: make<e=2>: The system cannot find the indicated file.

Comment: makefile:14: recipe for target 'clean' failed

Comment: make: *** [clean] Error 2

Comment: Any other idea? I read a comment in this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158931/compile-using-makefile-in-window), that rm was not defined in Windows. Is there any equivalent?

Comment: The Windows equivalent of `rm` is `del`. Doc here: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/del.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: That was the hint I needed, thanks a lot! It's working now :-)